# Lagrangian Equation for a Mass moves along Incline Plane

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics, classical-mechanics

A particle of mass m moves without friction on a plane making an angle of alpha with the horizontal (earths surface).

How do I determine Lagrange's equations of motion for this system?

Given that the particle starts at the origin with a velocity $v(0) = v_0(\hat{i} + \tan \alpha \hat{k})$, with $v_0 > 0$. Determine the maximum height reached by the particle and the time taken for the particle to return to earth.

Comment: Just find the lagrangian $L=T-V$ first by placed  the coordinate $x-z$ so that the vertex of the inclined plane coincide with origin.

Answer (score 2):

The Lagrangian of a particle in gravitational acceleration is
$$\mathcal{L}=\frac{m}{2}(\dot{x}^{2}+\dot{y}^{2}+\dot{z}^{2})-gz$$
The equation of a plane inclined by $\alpha$ may be written as
$$x\sin(\alpha)-z\cos{\alpha}=0$$
Thus
$$\dot{x}=\dot{z}\cot{\alpha}$$
So
$$\mathcal{L}=\frac{m}{2}(\dot{y}^{2}+[1+\cot^{2}{\alpha}]\dot{z}^{2})-gz$$
$y$ is a cyclic variable, so
$$p_{y}=m\dot{y}=const$$
Thus
$$\mathcal{L}=\frac{m}{2}\Big(\frac{p_{y}^{2}}{m^{2}}+[1+\cot^{2}{\alpha}]\dot{z}^{2}\Big)-gz$$
$$\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial{\dot{z}}}=\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial{z}}$$
$$\ddot{z}+\frac{g}{m[1+\cot^{2}{\alpha}]}=0$$
$$z(t)=-\frac{g}{2m[1+\cot^{2}{\alpha}]}t^{2}+v_{z0}t+z_{0}$$
$$z(t)=-\frac{g}{2m[1+\cot^{2}{\alpha}]}t^{2}+v_{0}\tan{\alpha}t+z_{0}$$
To find the maximum distance, extrimize
$$\frac{d}{dt}z(t)=0$$
$$t=\frac{m[1+\cot^{2}{\alpha}]v_{0}\tan{\alpha}}{g}$$
Hence, the maximum height is
$$z_{max}-z_{0}=\frac{mv_{0}^{2}(1+\cot^{2}{\alpha})\tan^{2}{\alpha}}{2g}$$$